# Ubuntu 17.04 - No keyboard after install. It works before on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, 17.04

I use Asus Asus E200HA laptop. Before - on Ubuntu 16.04 I had no problems with keyboard. I installed 17.04 and after installation I can't even put password. What should I do ?

Comment: Install 16.06 LTS.

Comment: Have you installed BIOS 303 from Jan 2017? See https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-Vivobook-E200HA/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: @Pilot6 16.06..?

Comment: I meant 16.04..

Comment: BIOS 303 solved the problem. Thanks.